# I need regex(7)'s manual, but man command shows regex(3)'s manual

Tags: command-line, manpage

I understand there are many manuals (which are displayed by `man` command) in Ubuntu that has same names and are distinguished by a number. For example there is `regex(3)` and `regex(7)`.
If I type `man regex` it shows `regex(3)`'s manual. Is there any way to tell `man` to show `regex(7)` manual?

**Note 1:** There is a `regex(7)` item in **see also** part of `regex(3)`'s manual.

**Note 2:** I tried `man regex(7)` and `man "regex(7)"` commands, but no success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access the `(7)` man section you can use the following command:

```
MANSECT=7 man regex
```

The section search order is predefined, that explains why you get `regex(3)` by default:

> ```
>    MANSECT
>           If $MANSECT is set, its value is a colon-delimited list of  sec‐
>           tions  and  it  is  used  to  determine which manual sections to
>           search and in what order.  The default is "1 n l 8  3  2  3posix
>           3pm 3perl 5 4 9 6 7", unless overridden by the SECTION directive
>           in /etc/manpath.config.
> ```

Or you can just type:

```
man 7 regex
```

See [`man man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/man.1).

Answer (score 6):

You can also view all available manpages for that term:

```
man -a regex
```

After quitting the first manpage, it will show you some options:

```
$ man -a regex
--Man-- next: regex(7) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
```